# Is there a way to repeat this one more time?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Im writing in nasm x86 assembly code that does *+*-_ where the blanks are user input. Now I already have it where it does this, but I need it to read the next line and do it there as well. Im new to assembly, and I don't want to use loops or pointers or anything. Maybe a way with Times?
this is my code:

```
segment .data 
    newline db 0xA, 0xD
    newlinelen equ $-newline
    
    segment .bss
    
       num1 resb 2
       num2 resb 2
       num3 resb 2
       ;num4 resb 2
       ;num5 resb 2
       ;num6 resb 2
       res resb 1   
       ;res2 resb 1
    
    section .text
       global main    ;must be declared for using gcc
        
    main:             ;tell linker entry point
    
    ;reading num 1
       mov eax, 3
       mov ebx, 0  
       mov ecx, num1 
       mov edx, 2
       int 0x80  
    
    ;reading num 2
       mov eax, 3
       mov ebx, 0
       mov ecx, num2 
       mov edx, 2
       int 0x80   
       
     ;reading num 3
       mov eax, 3
       mov ebx, 0  
       mov ecx, num3 
       mov edx, 2
       int 0x80    
      ;new line for next equation 
       mov edx, newline 
       mov ecx, newlinelen
       mov ebx, 1
       mov eax, 4
       int 0x80  
    
    
       ; moving the first number to eax register and second number to ebx
       ; and subtracting ascii '0' to convert it into a decimal number
        
       mov eax, [num1]
       sub eax, '0'
       mov ebx, [num2]
       sub ebx, '0'
       mov ecx, [num3] 
       sub ecx, '0'
    
       ; add ebx to eax
       add eax, ebx
       ; add '0' to to convert the sum from decimal to ASCII
       add eax, '0'
    
       ; storing the sum in memory location res
       mov [res], eax
       ;subtract ecx from eax
       sub eax, ecx
       mov [res], eax
       
    
       ; print the sum 
       mov eax, 4       
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, res         
       mov edx, 1   
       int 0x80
    
    
    exit:    
       int 0x80
```

My input with this was 1+2-1 and output was 2, which was right. I don't need to use it on any number above 4, or negative numbers.
And I have tried just repeating the whole thing with numbers 4, 5, 6 but it just gives me a blank ascii character as the result, which is the closest I've gotten to a result.

```
;;new equation?
   
   ;reading num 4
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 0  
   mov ecx, num4 
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80  

;reading num 5
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 0
   mov ecx, num5 
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80   
   
 ;reading num 6
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 0  
   mov ecx, num6 
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80


   ; moving the first number to eax register and second number to ebx
   ; and subtracting ascii '0' to convert it into a decimal number
    
   mov eax, [num4]
   sub eax, '0'
   mov ebx, [num5]
   sub ebx, '0'
   mov ecx, [num6] 
   sub ecx, '0'

   ; add ebx to eax
   add eax, ebx
   ; add '0' to to convert the sum from decimal to ASCII
   add eax, '0'

   ; storing the sum in memory location res
   mov [res2], eax
   ;subtract ecx from eax
   sub eax, ecx
   mov [res2], eax
   

   ; print the sum 
   mov eax, 4       
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, res2       
   mov edx, 1   
   int 0x80
```

Ive also tried replacing the eax with AL and the other equation with AH but it doesn't work like that which I also don't understand. And then I also tried to make each one byte and put in segment sign resb 1, for the + sign, which didn't work. I just want it to read one more line after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>   mov edx, newline 
>   mov ecx, newlinelen
> ```

You've inversed the registers here.

> ```
>   mov eax, [num1]
>   ...
>   mov [res], eax
> ```

Everything between these instructions should use the byte-sized registers instead. Use `AL`, `BL`, and `CL`. Currently you're overwriting memory that doesn't belong to the *res* variable!

> ```
>   ; add '0' to to convert the sum from decimal to ASCII
>   add eax, '0'
> ```

You should first do the subtraction and then the conversion back to ASCII, followed by storing the character once in the *res* variable using `mov [res], al`.

> ```
> exit:    
>    int 0x80
> ```

Your exit lacks the function number in the `eax` register!

---

> Is there a way to repeat this one more time?

Even if you don't like it, **a loop is the way to go**. The `times` operator is an assembly-time functionality. You could turn the whole thing into a macro and have it invoked twice, but then you can just as well write it a second time like you've done now.

Comment: For build time repetition you can use NASM's preprocessor `%rep` construct too.

Answer (score 0):

I just repeated the code instead with adding values 4, 5, and 6 but putting them in higher characters rather than the lower ones. also adding a read garbage character for the new line.

```
segment .data 
    newline db 0xA, 0xD
    newlinelen equ $-newline
    
    segment .bss
    ;defining all variables
       num1 resb 2
       num2 resb 2
       num3 resb 2
;variables for next equation
       num4 resb 2
       num5 resb 2
       num6 resb 2
;newlin for garbage character
       newlin resb 1
;result 1 and result 2
       res resb 1   
       res2 resb 1
    
    section .text
       global main    ;must be declared for using gcc
        
    main:             ;tell linker entry point
    
    ;reading num 1
       mov eax, 3
       mov ebx, 0  
       mov ecx, num1 
       mov edx, 2
       int 0x80  
    
    ;reading num 2
       mov eax, 3
       mov ebx, 0
       mov ecx, num2 
       mov edx, 2
       int 0x80   
       
     ;reading num 3
       mov eax, 3
       mov ebx, 0  
       mov ecx, num3 
       mov edx, 2
       int 0x80   
    
    
       ; moving the first number to eax register and second number to ebx
       ; and subtracting ascii '0' to convert it into a decimal number
        ;moving variables in lower halfs
       mov AL, [num1]
       sub AL, '0'
       mov BL, [num2]
       sub BL, '0'
       mov CL, [num3] 
       sub CL, '0'
    
       ; add ebx to eax
       add AL, BL

    
       ; storing the sum in memory location res
       mov [res], AL
       ;subtract ecx from eax
       sub AL, CL
       ; add '0' to to convert the sum from decimal to ASCII
       add AL, '0'
       mov [res], AL
       
    
       ; print the sum 
       mov eax, 4       
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, res         
       mov edx, 1   
       int 0x80
      
      ;new line for next equation
      mov eax, 4
      mov ebx, 1
      mov ecx, newline
      mov edx, newlinelen
      int 0x80
     
      ;;new equation?
      ;;skip garbage character
       mov eax, 3
       mov ebx, 0
       mov ecx, newlin
       mov edx, 1
       int 0x80
   
   ;reading num 4
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 0  
   mov ecx, num4 
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80  

;reading num 5
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 0
   mov ecx, num5 
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80   
   
 ;reading num 6
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 0  
   mov ecx, num6 
   mov edx, 2
   int 0x80


   ; moving the first number to eax register and second number to ebx
   ; and subtracting ascii '0' to convert it into a decimal number
;moving variables in higher halfs
   mov AH, [newlin]
   mov BH, [num4]
   sub BH, '0'
   mov CH, [num5]
   sub CH, '0'
   mov DH, [num6] 
   sub DH, '0'

   ; add ebx to eax
   add BH, CH
   ;subtract ecx from eax
   sub BH, DH
   ; add '0' to to convert the sum from decimal to ASCII
   add BH, '0'
   ;move ah into memory location res 2
   mov [res2], BH
   
   

   ; print the sum 
   mov eax, 4       
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, res2       
   mov edx, 1 
   int 0x80
    
    
    exit:    
       mov eax, 1
       int 0x80
```