# Multiplying then dividing in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm just trying to learn about multiplying and dividing in nasm, and been experimenting with user input but it hasn't been working for me. I am just trying to multiply 2*3/2 so my input is 2 3 2 and it prints out an ascii blank character. I'm guessing its adding or subtracting '0' to change ascii to ints? Where do I put sub '0' or add '0' and why?

```
segment .data 
    
    segment .bss
    ;defining all variables
       num1 resb 2 ;num1 2 bytes
       num2 resb 2 ;nums2 2 bytes
       num3 resb 2 ;num2 2 bytes
    ;result
       res resb 1
    
    section .text
       global _start    ;must be declared for using gcc
        
    _start:             ;tell linker entry point
    
         
       ;reading num 1
       mov eax, 3 ;read
       mov ebx, 0  ;input
       mov ecx, num1 ;variable
       mov edx, 2 ;bytes
       int 0x80  ;end
    
    ;reading num 2
       mov eax, 3 ;read
       mov ebx, 0 ;input
       mov ecx, num2 ;variable
       mov edx, 2 ;bytes
       int 0x80   ;end
       
     ;reading num 3
       mov eax, 3 ;read
       mov ebx, 0  ;input
       mov ecx, num3 ;variable
       mov edx, 2 ;bytes
       int 0x80 ;end
       ; and subtracting ascii '0' to convert it into a decimal number
       
     
  
       ;moving variables in lower halfs
       mov ax, [num1]
       sub ax, '0'
       mov bx, [num2]
       sub bx, '0'
       ; multiply al and bl
       mul bx
       sub ax, '0'
       mov cx, [num3]
       sub cx, '0'
     ;dividing ax/cx
       div cx
       add ax, '0'
       mov [res], ax
    

mov ebx,1 ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov eax,4 ;system call number (sys_write)
int 0x80 ;call kernel

mov ecx,res
mov edx, 1
mov ebx,1 ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov eax,4 ;system call number (sys_write)
int 0x80 ;call kernel
mov eax,1 ;system call number (sys_exit)
int 0x80 ;call kernel
     
  
    
    exit:    
       mov eax, 1
       int 0x80
```

but my output is always �  or just nothing. Am I just adding '0' or subtracting '0' from the numbers wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am just trying to multiply 2*3/2 so my input is 2 3 2

Because you're using these small single digit numbers, calculation can remain extremely simple.

However you seem to have a problem respecting the dimensions of things. I already told you this in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977153/is-there-a-way-to-repeat-this-one-more-time). Single digit numbers are to be stored in byte-sized registers, and a byte-sized result must be written to the byte-sized *res* variable with a byte-sized operation.

```
mov al, [num1]
sub al, '0'    ; Converting from character to number
mov bl, [num2]
sub bl, '0'    ; Converting from character to number
```

When you say "multiply al and bl", then why do you execute `mul bx` which multiplies `AX` with `BX` ?

```
mul bl         ; Product is in AX
```

At this point, you still need to do the division on the numbers, so you shouln't yet make any conversion with that `sub ax, '0'`.

```
mov cl, [num3]
sub cl, '0'    ; Converting from character to number
```

Again "dividing ax/cx" would require clearing `DX`, but more importantly, you actually need the byte-sized division here:

```
div cl         ; Divides AX by CL, producing quotient in AL
add al, '0'    ; Converting from number to character
mov [res], al  ; Storing the single character, so use byte-sized operation
```

---

> ```
> mov ebx,1 ;file descriptor (stdout)
> mov eax,4 ;system call number (sys_write)
> int 0x80 ;call kernel
> ```

These lines are redundant and could explain seeing � displayed because `ECX` and `EDX` are not setup at this point.

---

> To convert from character to number, you subtract 48.
> To convert from number to character, you add 48.

The ASCII code of "0" is 48, so subtracting 48 produces the number 0
The ASCII code of "1" is 49, so subtracting 48 produces the number 1
The ASCII code of "2" is 50, so subtracting 48 produces the number 2
...
The ASCII code of "9" is 57, so subtracting 48 produces the number 9